# Batch file to retrieve printer driver name; Perform action if specific driver name found

Tags: batch-file, printing, wmic

**Disclaimer: I'm not a programmer. I have a basic understanding of different languages, have a general aptitude for technology, and am learning as I go. I've been muddling through this task with hopes that I can figure it out, but now I'm stuck.**

I need to make a batch file that will query Windows and provide me the Driver Name of all printers installed, and if a specific driver name is present on the machine, perform another action (in this case run a command-line utility that will change the printer's preferences).

So far, I have "crowdsourced" some code from various resources on the internet, but I haven't been able to successfully get the batch file to do what I want.

CODE:

```
@echo
setlocal
wmic printer get DriverName >> printerlist.txt
set count=0
FOR /F "skip=1 delims= " %%G IN (printerlist.txt) DO call :loop %%G %%H %%I
:loop
if "%1"=="" goto :endloop
if "%1"=="HP" (
   if "%2"=="DeskJet" (
      if "%3"=="1000" (
         echo Found: HP DeskJet 1000
         )
      if "%3"=="2000" (
         echo Found: HP DeskJet 2000
         )
      if "%3"=="3000" (
         echo Found: HP DeskJet 3000
         )
      pause
      )
   )
SHIFT
goto :loop
:endloop
```

Essentially, I cobbled this together just as a test to have a message display in CMD if it finds any one of three specific Driver Names of printers. I will eventually replace the echo with some other operation, assuming I can get it to work. What I think is supposed to happen is that the batch file will grab all printer driver names and populate them into a .txt file (this part is working fine). Then, the batch file will loop and look inside the .txt file and, using space as a delimeter, find the specific printer models I'm looking for and display the echo. As it stands, if I run this batch file, it will create the .txt file, but then will exit without displaying any messages. I've looked in the .txt file and one of the printers is in the file, for example "HP DeskJet 1000". In case you're curious, I'm skipping line 1 because it just says "DriverName".

Any advice?

Comment: The WMIC output is UTF-16 with a BOM. That is probably part of your problem.

Comment: Can I just place |more before >> printerlist.txt to take care of that?

Answer (score 0):

Be advised I am not a programmer either. The following is hack coding and almost certainly not the most efficient solution. That said it should work.

#### Code:

```
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3* delims= " %%G IN ('wmic printer get DriverName') DO (
SET ONE=%%G
SET TWO=%%H
SET THREE=%%I
CALL :LOOP
)

GOTO ENDLOOP
:LOOP

if "%ONE%"=="" GOTO ENDLOOP
if %ONE%==HP GOTO FIRSTCHECK
GOTO :EOF

:FIRSTCHECK
if %TWO%==DESKJET GOTO SECONDCHECK
GOTO :EOF

:SECONDCHECK
if %THREE%==1000 GOTO 1000
if %THREE%==2000 GOTO 2000
if %THREE%==3000 GOTO 3000
GOTO :EOF

:1000
ECHO Found HP DeskJet 1000
pause
GOTO :EOF

:2000
ECHO Found HP DeskJet 2000
pause
GOTO :EOF

:3000
ECHO Found HP DeskJet 3000
pause
GOTO :EOF

:ENDLOOP
```